# How to take specific values from one dataframe and put in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

There are two dataframes(df and dfi) and I'm trying to locate  those user_id s which are same in both dataframes and want to create new column in df named new_country in which  I will save the countries whose user_id is same in both.

```
import pandas as pd


df =fb_comments_count
dfi=fb_active_users
df.sort_values(['created_at'])
df = df.loc[(df['created_at']<'2020/01/31') & (df['created_at']>'2019/12/01' )]

n=0

for x in df['user_id'].unique():
    
    df.at[n,'sum']=df.loc[df['user_id']==x ,'number_of_comments'].sum()   #this line works 
    
    n=n+1

df =df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['user_id'])
df = df.dropna()
df.sort_values('user_id')
m=0
dfi=dfi.drop(columns=['name','status'])
for y in df['user_id']:
    
    df.at[m,'new_country']=dfi.loc[dfi['user_id']==y ,'country']   #but this line doesn't and
    #print(dfi.loc[dfi['user_id']==y])                             # shows
    #print(y)                                                      #"Incompatible indexer with 
                                                                   #Series"
    m=m+1
   
df
```

it throws the error

```
Incompatible indexer with Series
```

But some strange index appears when I try to  print

```
print(dfi.loc[dfi['user_id']==y])
```

the code is given below

```
import pandas as pd


df =fb_comments_count
dfi=fb_active_users
df.sort_values(['created_at'])
df = df.loc[(df['created_at']<'2020/01/31') & (df['created_at']>'2019/12/01' )]

n=0

for x in df['user_id'].unique():
    
    df.at[n,'sum']=df.loc[df['user_id']==x ,'number_of_comments'].sum()
    
    n=n+1

df =df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['user_id'])
df = df.dropna()
df.sort_values('user_id')
m=0
dfi=dfi.drop(columns=['name','status'])
for y in df['user_id']:
    
    #df.at[m,'new_country']=dfi.loc[dfi['user_id']==y ,'country']
    print(dfi.loc[dfi['user_id']==y])
    #print(y)
    m=m+1
   
df
```

sample dataframe

```
fb_comments_count

user_id created_at  number_of_comments
18  2019-12-29 00:00:00 1
25  2019-12-21 00:00:00 1
78  2020-01-04 00:00:00 1
37  2020-02-01 00:00:00 1
41  2019-12-23 00:00:00 1
```

```
fb_active_users

user_id name       status       country
33  Amanda Leon     open        Australia
27  Jessica Farrell open        Luxembourg
18  Wanda Ramirez   open        USA
50  Samuel Miller   closed      Brazil
16  Jacob York      open        Australia
```

Comment: Please make your question more focused. Provide a **minimal reproducible** example of data, the matching expected output, and carefully explain the desired logic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think you should add a small dataset for the community to reproduce the error, so that we can help you